# Customize a widget position

Tags: plugins, customization, widgets

I want to add a image button like a flag for changing language to top bar of my WordPress site , but the theme I using doesn't allow me have widget there , Can I have widget every where in my page ?

[image]

result should be this :

[image]

I used page builder by SiteOrigin but I can not fix this , is there any good plugin that can allow me to do this?

Comment: Sorry, plugin recommendations are off topic. Also, I don't think such plugins exist. Your best course of action is making a child theme in which you define a sidebar in the desired place.

Comment: @cjbj , I should convert a joomla website to wordpress , how can I achieve the exact desgin as joomla one in word press?

Comment: That question is far too broad to answer in general. It depends on the site.